# How to show a yes or no before deleting a record without using javascript?

Tags: php

I want to display a message using php only which says do want to delete this record ?
Then yes or no.  Please help

```
echo "<tr bgcolor='#cccccc'><td>$hometeam</td> <td>Vs</td><td>$awayteam</td><td>$date</td><td>$venue</td><td><a href='fixtures.php?fixture_id=$fixture_id&edit=1' name='edit' >Edit</a></td><td><a href='fixtures.php?fixture_id=$fixture_id&delete=1' name='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: If you want to do it server-side, then you have to load a new page with a from or something where the user can chose Yes or No – and on submit of that you either delete the record or not, and then redirect back to the original page.

Comment: This site is not for asking code solutions but to ask help about what you tried and failed to achieve. -1 (also, i hate question askers like you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fixtures.php, you have to check the `delete` field of $_GET array and add a confirmation.
Something like that using only PHP :

```
  if (! empty ($_GET['delete']) && ! empty ($_GET['fixture_id']) && empty ($_GET['confirm']))
{
   $fixture_id = intval($_GET['fixture_id']);
   echo "Are you sure you want to delete this record ?<br />";
   echo "<a href='fixtures.php?fixture_id=$fixture_id&delete=1&confirm=1'>YES</a> - "
   echo "<a href='fixtures.php?fixture_id=$fixture_id'>NO</a> - "
}
else if (! empty ($_GET['delete']) && ! empty ($_GET['fixture_id']) && ! empty ($_GET['confirm']))
{
 mysqli_query ("DELETE FROM fixtures WHERE fixture_id=".intval($_GET['fixture_id']));
}
```

Comment: Really your answer worked for me and I learned a lot from it : Thanks once again

Comment: @humphrey it's a pleasure. Lot of people suggest you some Javascript code, it's not answer to your problem because you ask "only PHP" but, thing is you have to reload the page twice (confirmation && delete) for deleting your fixtures. You can do the same with 1 reload with JS, and better with 0 reload with JS and Ajax :-)

Comment: Yes u understood the problem and u solved it according to the requirements that what they call programming : u a star

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm_delete() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete that?");
    }
</script>
```

Then in the link, add `onclick='return confirm_delete();'`

**Edit: My mistake, didn't see the 'PHP only' bit...**

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.

```
if(empty($_GET[verification])){?>
            <center>Really wanna delete?<br> <a href="?XY&verification=YZ">Yes</a> <a href="javascript:history.back()">No</a></center>
        <?}else{
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM XY WHERE id='$_GET[id]'");
            jsAlert("has been deleted");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something i use:

> script>
>
> jQuery(document).ready(function(){
>
> ```
>            jQuery(".deleteID").click(function () {
>                if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')) {
>                    return false;
>                }
>            });
>        });
>    </script>
> ```

And in your HTML use the deleteID for ID.

Comment: And the “without JavaScript” part of the question you just missed?